# Blender Modal Operator Gets Slower With Each Execution

Tags: scripting, add-on, operator

I am working on a Blender addon and I'm suffering with a huge problem with performance.

I have created a modal operator and while the actual code is very complex here is a sample that is still able to recreate the same problem. I am using a modal operator because there is no way to report my progress back to Blender if I'm using a basic operator or just making a script run call.

```py
    def modal(self, context, event):

        if self.state == 2:
            #Does something, only called one time in the end
            return {'FINISHED'}
        elif self.state == 0:
            #Does something, only called one time in the beginning
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

        elif self.state == 1: #Where the issue is. On each new execution this part gets slower and slower. It's called 100s of times. In the following log, 240 times exactly

            layerStartTime = time.time()
            try:
                currentLayer = self.listOfParsedLayers.pop(0) # listOfParsedLayers is a List containing lists of objects of a user defined class. 
                #listOfParsedLayers is populated in the invoke() function
            except IndexError:
                self.state = 2
                return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

            
            #Below two lines create a new collection and link it to the scene. The problem still exists even if I comment these two lines out. 
            layerCollection = bpy.data.collections.new("Layer " + str(currentLayer.layerNumber))
            self.parentCollection.children.link(layerCollection)


            for elem in currentLayer.gcodes: #Each one of these `elem`s is roughly the same size. The variation in size is negligible
                print(elem, end='\r', flush=True)
                print(" " * len(elem.__str__()), end='\r', flush=True)

            layerEndTime = time.time()
            layerTimeTaken = layerEndTime - layerStartTime

            print("Layer Done: {}/{}. Processed {} lines/s".format(currentLayer.layerNumber, self.numberOfLayers, len(currentLayer.gcodes)/layerTimeTaken), end='\n', flush=True)
            
            #This is the status reporting I cannot lose. It is a string that is shown in the addon side panel.
            bpy.context.scene.Stitcher_Props.Status = "Layer Done: {}/{}".format(currentLayer.layerNumber, self.numberOfLayers)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

```
Layer Done: 0/240. Processed 99864.38095238095 lines/s                                                                                        
Layer Done: 1/240. Processed 131382.99796028805 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 2/240. Processed 159292.78861375354 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 3/240. Processed 162140.667184399 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 4/240. Processed 162928.60274615657 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 5/240. Processed 146341.95625650944 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 6/240. Processed 164387.70720461095 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 7/240. Processed 161683.34893315283 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 8/240. Processed 31140.085639301993 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 9/240. Processed 160100.03930461072 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 10/240. Processed 133947.06391810934 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 11/240. Processed 77873.7837885103 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 12/240. Processed 9964.28099963616 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 13/240. Processed 30149.528307990942 lines/s                                                                                                      
Layer Done: 14/240. Processed 17027.66779537593 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 15/240. Processed 15721.659918519408 lines/s                                                                                                      
Layer Done: 16/240. Processed 16479.150725422034 lines/s                                                                                                      
Layer Done: 17/240. Processed 15762.26056642093 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 18/240. Processed 16314.317159968752 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 19/240. Processed 11530.099561903391 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 20/240. Processed 16056.008655678641 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 21/240. Processed 14822.037499442415 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 22/240. Processed 13872.080731720363 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 23/240. Processed 12978.123577635903 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 24/240. Processed 15712.772026887016 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 25/240. Processed 17275.93793078029 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 26/240. Processed 17430.209104502243 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 27/240. Processed 23530.315584181062 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 28/240. Processed 21968.71754767077 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 29/240. Processed 25423.222487011353 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 30/240. Processed 18506.10602924788 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 31/240. Processed 23966.65979653851 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 32/240. Processed 48492.785715129256 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 33/240. Processed 147976.61308411215 lines/s                                                                                                       
Layer Done: 34/240. Processed 20398.098630232842 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 35/240. Processed 22183.27061390499 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 36/240. Processed 17178.37899379678 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 37/240. Processed 21069.219196944763 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 38/240. Processed 20101.42274633061 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 39/240. Processed 20930.953064452104 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 40/240. Processed 20916.825328364346 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 41/240. Processed 23753.37499049791 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 42/240. Processed 28772.32244139562 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 43/240. Processed 17973.050280785985 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 44/240. Processed 16124.705715451997 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 45/240. Processed 15655.06738468312 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 46/240. Processed 22488.346087464986 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 47/240. Processed 16086.314203070151 lines/s                                                                                                        
Layer Done: 48/240. Processed 16273.093981214251 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 49/240. Processed 22105.272761141478 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 50/240. Processed 16802.185915179503 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 51/240. Processed 22507.319261238154 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 52/240. Processed 16479.673660976223 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 53/240. Processed 21624.785475732995 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 54/240. Processed 15401.053531470134 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 55/240. Processed 20809.55456712191 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 56/240. Processed 22765.937738626708 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 57/240. Processed 15540.037074009919 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 58/240. Processed 20283.536472622847 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 59/240. Processed 20338.38408528338 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 60/240. Processed 14714.454760544995 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 61/240. Processed 20578.027435422544 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 62/240. Processed 24987.29904114816 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 63/240. Processed 14915.492770987486 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 64/240. Processed 21886.31894934334 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 65/240. Processed 29375.320969905308 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 66/240. Processed 19374.86567332338 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 67/240. Processed 20176.82540432062 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 68/240. Processed 22807.64508117435 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 69/240. Processed 24547.116391530184 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 70/240. Processed 21734.008624068993 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 71/240. Processed 23405.143500620423 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 72/240. Processed 22763.58553883411 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 73/240. Processed 32909.717732016026 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 74/240. Processed 17479.01493945589 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 75/240. Processed 23371.39038692051 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 76/240. Processed 23675.685865461113 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 77/240. Processed 21899.5053015301 lines/s                                                                                                           
Layer Done: 78/240. Processed 21745.86065825174 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 79/240. Processed 23499.876075286204 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 80/240. Processed 19723.018432326833 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 81/240. Processed 20446.516371926984 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 82/240. Processed 19212.534571340144 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 83/240. Processed 18777.09223052796 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 84/240. Processed 20222.92784857292 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 85/240. Processed 19544.02220528382 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 86/240. Processed 18133.19208258252 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 87/240. Processed 19010.905058417127 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 88/240. Processed 16729.449020559718 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 89/240. Processed 19638.75111242035 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 90/240. Processed 18671.102369720156 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 91/240. Processed 26132.73520249221 lines/s                                                                                                          
Layer Done: 92/240. Processed 29548.374385127725 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 93/240. Processed 28710.941706959307 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 94/240. Processed 28566.017835565275 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 95/240. Processed 29132.588191049268 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 96/240. Processed 28434.171367164727 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 97/240. Processed 29504.695914177064 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 98/240. Processed 18355.951432276317 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 99/240. Processed 18040.927948303717 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 100/240. Processed 16845.655142495296 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 101/240. Processed 24766.613894910704 lines/s                                                                                                         
Layer Done: 102/240. Processed 29228.06980592022 lines/s
```

These are the first 102 lines of the print message and it only gets worse after this. Number of lines in each segment is not drastically different. The trend is just that the execution time keeps increasing and increasing and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the print statements ? It seems you're printing thousands of them per iteration and print is notoriously slow. No idea why it would get slower though. Without seeing what's inside `currentLayer.gcodes` it's a bit of a guess work. Also, are you familiar with f-strings ? I think they're way easier to read than `.format` notation

Comment: @Gorgious, the point is later runs take significantly longer than previous loops when the data is more or less consistent

Comment: Yeah I do understand what you think is happening, I'm trying to help you find the reason with what limited knowledge of your codebase I have :) At a quick glance I would not say that it takes longer and longer to compute. It looks like after the 10th iteration they all more or less take the same time to compute. The numbers looks statistically samey. Maybe you ought to check what happens in the first 10 of your layers.

Comment: @Gorgious, I think I found out the reason. every time I create a new object the time for object creation goes higher. That's the issue. I'd have to think of a way to resolve that.

Comment: That's a known issue of Blender. There has been a patch adressing this in a recent version. What version do you use ?

Comment: @Gorgious I'm on 3.3.0, I'd try with 3.4.1 if that gives a better result. If it does that would be just amazing

Comment: @Gorgious. I tried with 3.4.1. The same problem seems to exist. Thanks anyway. I'd see what I can do :D